# Issue in Intercepting Burpsuite requests from iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, penetration-testing, burp

I am testing an application from iPad and using Burpsuite to capture the traffic. But, in that case, I was not able to capture the following requests for that application:

1. Login Request
2. Two Factor Authentication Request
3. Video Search Request in application
4. Video Play request in application

How can I capture above mentioned requests ?

(**NOTE:** I was able to capture some simple GET and POST requests of that application.)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed the Burp Certificate? If not, use these [instructions](https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/1841109-Mobile%20Set-up_iOS%20Device%20-%20Installing%20CA%20Certificate.html).

If you have, it's likely that this application uses certificate pinning. There are some tools that can disable certificate pinning, including [Burp Mobile Assistant](https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/2798916-installing-burp-suite-mobile-assistant). You need a jailbroken device running iOS 8 or 9. Be aware that Mobile Assistant cannot always disable pinning.

Comment: Already installed it ! I think you should have read the note I have added, that I am able to capture simple GET POST requests of application.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17892024)

Comment: @iamjayp - I did read your question; you didn't say if the simple requests were HTTPS. Did you try the mobile assistant?

Comment: @AnshulParashar - Those links are supplemental information, not the answer.

Answer (score -1):

It was the issue of the system on which I am running the burpsuite, which is why the system was not able to process requests and responses.